# RabbitMQ synchronous messaging pros and cons

Tags: asynchronous, rabbitmq, messaging, synchronous

as we all know message bus like rabbitMQ is mainly meant for asynchronous messaging so standard approch is to fire and forget like publish something on bus and don't worry about who will process published message or when. But i'm thinking about latest talk in our development team about synchronous processing of message: case would be to publish message to service bus and as as publisher i want to wait for any subscriber to process message and return results to me - so it looks rather as request-response model. I'm thinking now of one con like degrading performance in this model. What are your thoughts? When to use async and when sync? What are the tradeoffs?

Answer (score 22):

Synchronous messaging is possible but **impacts scalability**. If a publisher has to wait for its recipients to respond, then it will be limited in how much it can achieve at any given time.

However, you can achieve request-response using asynchronous messaging. In RabbitMQ, you do this by means of the [Remote Procedure Call (RPC)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html) pattern.

To put it simply, your publisher publishes a message, but *doesn't wait for the response*; it can continue doing other stuff in the meantime. The publisher does keep track of it though, by putting a CorrelationId on the message, and storing it locally. The message eventually reaches a consumer, who processes it and responds back to the publisher *on a different queue*. The reply has the same CorrelationId. When the publisher receives the reply, it can then mark that particular call (via the CorrelationId) as processed.

If you want, you can also do other things with the CorrelatonId, such as timeout those messages for which we haven't received a reply after e.g. 30 seconds.

Comment: can u provide sample code for request - response way?

Comment: You can find it in the link I provided.